# Angular2/Ionic2 + ng2-dragula Did anyone get it to work?

Tags: angular, ionic2, dragula, ng2-dragula

Im trying to add drag and drop into my ionic 2 app.  But can't get it to work.

This is what I have done so far:

```
npm install ng2-dragula dragula --save
```

then in my page:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/dragtest/dragtest.html',
  directives: [Dragula],
  viewProviders: [DragulaService],
})
export class DragtestPage {
  constructor(private nav: NavController) {
  }
}
```

But when I add [dragula] tags, I get error:
Can't bind 'dragula' since it isn't a know native property.

Did any one get this to work with ionic 2, are there any examples?

Comment: Did you found a solution?

I'm facing the same problems...

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss the import statement:

import {DragulaService, Dragula} from 'ng2-dragula/ng2-dragula';

I already tried this but it seems the IDE can't find the directory 'ng2-dragula' (red text in PHP Storm)

Answer (score 0):

I did ;) After installing it import the module and the service in the app.module.ts:

```
import { DragulaModule, DragulaService } from 'ng2-dragula/ng2-dragula';
```

then add the module to the imports:

```
imports: [
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
DragulaModule
],
```

and the service to the providers:

```
providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}, DragulaService]
```

After that you just have to import the service in the components you will use it:

```
import { DragulaService } from 'ng2-dragula/ng2-dragula';
```

and pass it to the constructor:

```
constructor(private dragulaService: DragulaService ) {}
```

Finally follow the steps shown [here.](https://devdactic.com/ionic-2-drag-and-drop/)(only for the template, not the imports )

Answer (score 0):

i just write a tutorial about how to make latest version ng-dragula work for ionic 2, on ng-dragula github page, they have code example there, but if you just copy and paste wouldn't work, we need to make some little change to make it work.

write a article about it few weeks ago, hope this will help

http://etenbo.com/add-drag-and-drop-on-ionic-2-by-plugin-dragula/